# Scope_Identity() always returns 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scope-identity

The following stored procedure inserts a new row correctly but, always returns 0 for the output parameter. What would return the new row ID?

```
alter procedure DlogErr 
    @Msg varchar(100), @Cmd nvarchar(max), 
    @Stk varchar(200), @Pgm varchar(50), 
    @Lin smallint, @EID int, @UID int output 
as
begin
    set nocount on

    insert into ErrorLog (Src, ErrMsg, Cmd, StackInfo, Itm, Pgm, Lin, ErrID) 
    values ('VFP', @Msg, @Cmd, @Stk, '', @Pgm, @Lin, @EID);

    set @UID = Scope_Identity();
end
```

Comment: Works correctly for me. Did you have identity column in the table?

Comment: If you have a `uniqueidentifier` column that is assigned a default value from `NewId()` then you would want to use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?

Comment: Table definition please. You did not by chance overlook to put in an identity field?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you might have forgot to append `out` keyword while calling the stored procedure:

```
declare @varUID int
exec DlogErr @Msg='abc', @Cmd = 'foo', @Stk ='', @Pgm = '', @Lin = 0, @EID = 0 , @UID =  @varUID out
select @varUID
```